# Retrieving column name in Django Models

Tags: python, django

How do I retrieve names of the columns of a table in **MySQL** using **Models** in **Django**?

If I were using a **MySQLdb API**. I could have done it using the following:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
for k in cur.description:
    print k[0]
```

But I don't want to do it in the above manner.

I have the following defined in **models.py**

```
class Third(models.Model):
    studentname = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    rollnumber = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

My output should list **"studentname", "rollnumber","college"**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Listing the fields of your 'Third' model class in python2:

```
for field in Third._meta.fields:
  print field.name
```

And python3:

```
print("Third fields:")
for field in Third._meta.fields:
    print( f"- {field.name}" )
```

Comment: Note that this covers the specific case, but won't work e.g. for ForeignKey fields.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would also cover ForeignKey fields and manually-specified column names.

```
print(f'{"Field name":20} {"Column name"}')
print(50 * '-')
for f in Third._meta.fields:
    print(f'{f.name:20} {f.db_column or f.attname}')
```